# Ruby, net/ssh with proxy connection to router, channel hangs

Tags: ruby, shell, ssh

My current network setup is like this: 
LocalMachine <---SSH---> Server <---Telnet---> Router.
I am trying to connect to the Router from LocalMachine via Server (direct connection is not possible, Server acts as sort of proxy). Ruby's net/ssh gem is used for the ssh connection to the Server.

```
require 'net/ssh'


@hostname = "10.16.96.40"
@username = "server_username"
@password = "server_password"

Net::SSH::start(@hostname, @username, :password => @password) do |session|
    session.open_channel do |channel|
        channel.send_channel_request "shell" do |ch, success|
            if success
                puts "user shell started successfully"
            else
                puts "could not start user shell"
            end
        end

        channel.send_data("telnet 192.168.11.201\n")
        channel.send_data("router_username\n")
        channel.send_data("router_password\n")
        channel.send_data("sh ip int brief\n")    

    channel.on_data do |ch, data|
            print data
        end   
    end     
    session.loop
end
```

The script gets connected to the router. It gets the printout. But then the session hangs when expected it to be closed.

When I stop script execution manually with Ctrl+C I get the following message:

```
^C/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/ruby_compat.rb:25:in `select': Interrupt
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/ruby_compat.rb:25:in `io_select'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:210:in `process'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `block in loop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `loop'
    from 25_net_ssh_channel_shell.rb:33:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:240:in `start'
    from 25_net_ssh_channel_shell.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Any idea how to close the channel/session and get rid of the blinking cursor?